# Inserting data in middle of string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, split, concatenation

What functions can I use to print @string2 just like FORMAT 01)
Meaning whenever Gender data is missing, how can i design a query that will concat it in the right position?

```
-- FORMAT 01: 1) NAME 2) AGE 3) GENDER 4) CITY

declare @string1 varchar(max) = 'Name ABC; Age 50; Gender Male; City Tokyo';
select @string1;

-- FORMAT 02: 1) NAME 2) AGE 4) CITY
declare @string2 varchar(max) = 'Name: DEF; Age 30; City Delhi';
select @string2;
```

REQUIRED RESULT for string2:

```
Name: DEF; Age 30; Gender; City Delhi;
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: MS SQL 2016.......

Answer (score 1):

I think that would be the easiest solution

```
SELECT @string2, 
    IIF(PATINDEX('%Gender%',@string2) = 0, 
        REPLACE(@string2, 'City', 'Gender; City'), @string2)
```

Comment: Thank you this helps. Now for example if Name is also missing and I want to add Name and Gender, I will have to use two separate queries mentioned above?